# What is the most universal video format specs to play on the widest amount of devices?

Tags: video, mobile, cross-browser, video-encoding, mpeg

I know that MPEG is the most universal format, but I'd like more specs on what codec to use, bitrate, frames per second, etc. I'm looking at a format that'll play on most devices including IE 6-9, FF 3.6/4, Safari 4/5, and the majority of Android, Apple, Windows, and Blackberry devices.

Now I know that it would be nicer to play the video in some spiffy video player, but my primary concern is to get it playing on the most devices possible. I could care less if the video plays in the browser through a plugin like Quicktime or launches a video player like Windows Media Player.

Answer (score 1):

Going forward - H.264 video compression will become defacto standard. MPEG1,2, and MPEG4 will be over ridden by this; however, MPEG4 may continue for some time.

However, since Google has proposed to use On2 for HTML5 canvas, that last tussle may continue.